# Algorithm to get x amount of numbers that add up to a certain number. With most of the numbers being common. e.g. Input: 8, x = 3 Output: 3,3,2

Tags: algorithms

Want to know if there is an algorithm to get x amount of numbers that add up to a certain number. With most of the numbers being common. e.g. Input: 8, x = 3 Output: 3,3,2

Output should not be 2,2,4. The output numbers should be as close as possible.

Input: 10, x = 4 Output: 3,3,3,1

To clarify, the range of the numbers that add to the sum must be minimal.

Each number must be greater than 0.

My current attempt.

y = target, x = amount of numbers to reach y

y/x = z    Round down z to the nearest integer.

a = y - (z*x-1) 
output: z repeated x-1 times + a

10/3 = 3

4 = 10 - (3*2)

output: 3,3,4

Thank you

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't work for the example you gave with $y=8, x=3$ (it produces $2, 2, 4$). Instead of rounding down, why not round to the nearest integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is ALMOST correct. "Round down z to the nearest integer"- instead of this, just round z to the highest integer(and obviously it'll remain the same if z is integer). For eg, if z=1.4 or 1.6, z will become 2.

Comment: Ah right, that's working for all the cases that mine was failing. Thanks

Comment: @MaazSelia welocme